# C++ MPI code Seg Fault 11 when run

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, mpi

I'm trying to create something of server using MPI and I can get it to compile but when I run it it seg faults right away.  I've tried to add print statements to see where it crashes but that's not helping.  I'm new to using MPI and I can't find where the issue is.  I'm using a Mac and I'm trying to figure out llvm because I can't use GDB to check the core dump so any help in the meantime is greatly appreciated.

```
#include "mpi.h" 
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
using namespace std;

void error(const char *msg)
{
    perror(msg);
    exit(1);
}

int main( int argc, char **argv ) 
{ 
    int MAX_DATA = 255;
    MPI_Comm client; 
    MPI_Status status; 
    char port_name[MPI_MAX_PORT_NAME]; 
    int size, again; 
    double buf[MAX_DATA];
    cout << "Did we get here? [1]"; 
    MPI_Init(NULL, NULL);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size); 
    cout << "Did we get here before it pukes";
    if (size != 1) error("ERROR");

    // Create the random list
    list<int> rand_list;
    list<int>::iterator it;
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    {
        int r;
        r = rand();
        rand_list.insert (it,r);
        it++;
     }

     cout << "mylist contains:";
     for (it=rand_list.begin(); it!=rand_list.end(); ++it)
    {
        cout << ' ' << *it;
        cout << '\n';
    }

    MPI_Open_port(MPI_INFO_NULL, port_name); 
    printf("server available at %s\n",port_name); 
    while (1) { 
        MPI_Comm_accept( port_name, MPI_INFO_NULL, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &client); 
    again = 1; 
    while (again) { 
        MPI_Recv( buf, MAX_DATA, MPI_DOUBLE,  
                  MPI_ANY_SOURCE, MPI_ANY_TAG, client, &status ); 
        switch (status.MPI_TAG) { 
            case 0: MPI_Comm_free( &client ); 
                    MPI_Close_port(port_name); 
                    MPI_Finalize(); 
                    return 0; 
            case 1: MPI_Comm_disconnect( &client ); 
                    again = 0; 
                    break; 
            case 2: /* do something */ 
                cout << "Why did we get here?"; 
            default: 
                    /* Unexpected message type */ 
                    MPI_Abort( MPI_COMM_WORLD, 1 ); 
            } 
        } 
        } 
 }

[asdfa:04443] *** Process received signal ***
[asdfa:04443] Signal: Segmentation fault: 11 (11)
[asdfa:04443] Signal code: Address not mapped (1)
[asdfa:04443] Failing at address: 0x0
[asdfa:04443] [ 0] 0   libsystem_platform.dylib            0x00007fff8ed1452a _sigtramp + 26
[asdfa:04443] [ 1] 0   ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
[asdfa:04443] [ 2] 0   server.o                            0x000000010a40eba2 main + 834
[asdfa:04443] [ 3] 0   libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff9cb245ad start + 1
[asdfa:04443] *** End of error message ***
Segmentation fault: 11 (core dumped)
```

Comment: You might add the commands you used to compile and run....

Comment: Here, under linux and gcc, it is failing on the first invocation of `rand_list.insert(it,r);`

Comment: Why can't you use `gdb` to examine the core dump?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is is located at these lines of code:

```cpp
list<int>::iterator it;
for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
{
    int r;
    r = rand();
    rand_list.insert (it,r);
    it++;
 }
```

There are two problems:

- You declared the iterator, but you never assigned a valid value to it, so it is pointing to anywhere. The iterator must, however, point to a valid location within list. Both `rand_list.begin()` and `rand_list.end()` are legal, so you need:

  `list<int>::iterator it = rand_list.end();`
- Then the first parameter is the position you insert your element. The new element is inserted *before* the location the iterator points to. So no matter if you initially chose begin() or end() as iterator (they are the same for the empty list anyway), by incrementing it, you increment it beyond the list's end, which is undefined behaviour. Simply insert always at the end:

  `rand_list.insert (rand_list.end(), r);`

But why don't you simply use `push_back` (or `push_front`, if you prefer)?